# How can I get rid of blank spaces caused by PLSQL linesize being larger than the data in each line?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, toad

I have a script, in which I have set the LINESIZE to 1000.

As a result, the lines which I am outputting via dbms_output.put_line are coming out with however many extra spaces are needed to make the line complete with 1000 characters.

How can I change the linesize parameter or the script to allow the content to set the line size and avoid the blanks in my output file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try SET TRIMSPOOL ON along with SET LINESIZE hope this will help you to remove extra space at the end of records.

Comment: So true; much simpler than my suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Hm, if there is a way, I don't know it. A simple procedure (which simulates what you described) does exactly what you said - makes each line 1000 characters long, although I **TRIMMED** the result (see line 3):

```
SQL> set linesize 1000
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> spool a.txt
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in (select empno ||' '||ename col from emp) loop
  3      dbms_output.put_line(trim(cur_r.col)) ;
  4    end loop;
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> spool off
```

Therefore, I'd suggest another approach - **UTL_FILE**. Here's how.

First, as SYS, create a directory (object) which points to a directory in your database server's file system. I have 11gXE on my laptop, so I chose its Temp directory. Also, grant *read* and *write* privileges on that directory to user which will be using it (Scott in my example):

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> create directory ext_dir as 'c:\temp';

Directory created.

SQL> grant read, write on directory ext_dir to scott;

Grant succeeded.
```

Now, the procedure itself:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> declare
  2    v_file utl_file.file_type;
  3  begin
  4    v_file := utl_file.fopen(location     => 'EXT_DIR',
  5                             filename     => 'test.txt',
  6                             open_mode    => 'w',
  7                             max_linesize => 1000);
  8    for cur_r in (select empno ||' '|| ename result from emp) loop
  9      utl_file.put_line(v_file, cur_r.result);
 10    end loop;
 11    utl_file.fclose(v_file);
 12  end;
 13  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

If you check the output file's contents, you'll see that lines have variable size, as long as each line's contents.

Hopefully, it'll help.

Comment: I chose the other solution because it answered the specific question, but you're right that I should have been using utl_file, and this is the answer I used.

Comment: Absolutely; I upvoted SET TRIMSPOOL ON answer for the same reason.